# How to prevent Sockets from bundling two messages into a single event?

Tags: dart, sockets

It appears that by default, `Socket`/`ServerSocket` may merge two events into a single event

Such that when doing:

```dart
clientSocket.add([1,2,3]);
clientSocket.add([4,5,6]);
```

then listened with:

```dart
serverSocket.listen(print);
```

there are two possible outputs.

The first is one print per event:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

The second is that both events are in a single print:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Is it possible to disable this?

I am aware of `Socket.setOptions` with `SocketOption` and in particular `SocketOption.tcpNoDelay` which seems related to this behavior.
But after trying to use `setOptions` in various ways both on the client & server, I failed to obtain the desired behavior (which is never merging two events into one)

Comment: TCP is a byte-stream protocol. Not a message protocol.. If you want messages you have to implement them yourself, somehow. There are many techniques.

Comment: Right, but the Dart implementation could offer ways to do this natively instead of manually implementing it. That's what I'm asking.

Comment: So you're asking why Dart is designed the way it is? or why a feature you think should be there isn't there? If so, (a) it doesn't appear in your question, and (b) it is entirely opinion-based.

Comment: I'm asking if there's an official way to separate the messages in Dart. My understanding is that this is what `SocketOption.tcpNoDelay` is supposed to do, but I may be wrong. I know how to do it by hand, but I figured Dart likely has something more official as it often does.

Comment: Noi, it isn't what `Socket.tcpNoDelay` is supposed to do. TCP has no message boundaries, and socket options therefore cannot provide them. The only 'official' way is whatever the other end expects. There are lots of options: lines, XML, length-word prefixes, ... It isn't up to a language to define a wire protocol. It is up to the peers to do that.

Comment: Alright then. I guess I'll keep my length algorithm. Thanks!